# Error "Configuration failed" when i install SharePoint Foundation 2010 on win 8i 64bit? Please help me!

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Error when i finish installation SharePoint Foundation 2010 on win 8 64bit
I installed Sharepoint 2010 Foundation on Window 8 Pro 64bit, i have been successfull SQL server 2008 R2 and addition software for SharePoint. BUt at the final i was failed at these error. So please people help me for this error. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us what is in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows 8, setup Hyper-V and install a Networking operating system on it. SharePoint isn't designed to run on windows 8.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/get-started-with-windows-8-client-hyper-v-the-right-way/